# Scope of the local variable "node" in insert method of LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

In the code below where

```
Node node = new Node(data);
node.next = head;
head = node;
```

the scope of the "local" variable "node" is within the block defined inside the method insert, right?
So I was under the impression that when we are out of method "insert" we lose access to the variable "node" and that gives me the (wrong) impression that "head" is no longer pointing to valid memory location.

How come this does not the case here?

in other words, So "head" refers to that address of memory which was allocated during execution of local code "node = new Node(data)" right? Wasn't that allocation applied on stack memory? Isn't it the case the every time a function call is completed the stack memory assigned to that call is released?

Here is the entire code:

```
public class LinkedList {
    public Node head;

    public void insert (int data){
        if (head == null){
            head = new Node(data);
        } else {
            Node node = new Node(data);
            node.next = head;
            head = node;
        }
    }
}


class Node {
    public int data;
    Node next; 
    Node (int data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to differentiate between variables, values, references, and objects.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis perhaps if I new how to differentiate those I wouldn't asked this question, right?

Comment: Those were keywords which I was expecting you to look up, but, here, let me write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few concepts we care about here: variables, objects, and reference values.

A variable is a container for a value. An object is a data structure (with some behavior) which is addressable in memory. A reference value is a value for reference types. It is a pointer to an object.

This is explained in the JVMS [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.4)

> There are three kinds of reference types: class types, array types,
>   and interface types. Their values are references to dynamically
>   created class instances, arrays, or class instances or arrays that
>   implement interfaces, respectively.

and in the JLS [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)

> The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these
>   objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.

What you have here

```
Node node = new Node(data);
```

is a variable named `node` of type `Node` which after its initialization stores a value which refers to an object of type `Node`.

When you then do

```
head = node;
```

you copy the reference value stored in `node` and store that copy in the variable named `head`.

Once execution leaves the `else` block, the variable `node` is no longer in scope, so you cannot use. The variable `head` however is still storing the value that was assigned to it.

---

Note that [*scope*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) is

> the region of the program within which the entity declared by the
>   declaration can be referred to using a simple name, provided it is
>   visible (§6.4.1).

It has nothing to do with how long a value is valid or how long an object will remain in memory.

Comment: So head refers to that address of memory which was allocated during execution of local code node = new Node(data); right? Wasn't that allocation applied on stack memory? Isn't it the case the every time a function call is completed the stack memory assigned to that call  is released?

Comment: @Cgraphics All objects (minus a few special cases in some JVMs) are allocated on the heap. The value returned by the new instance creation expression `new Node(data)` is a reference value which refers to memory on the heap.